# Assigning Purview roles to Service Principal through Powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-purview

I am trying to add a collection to my purview account and to do so I need my service principle to have "Data Source Admin" role in my purview account. I have deployed my purview account using this Powershell script:

```
function deployPurviewAccount([string]$resourceGroup, [string]$location, [string]$purviewName){
New-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -Location $location

New-AzPurviewAccount -Name $purviewName `
-ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
-Location $location `
-IdentityType SystemAssigned `
-SkuCapacity 1 `
-SkuName Standard `
}
$location = getLocation
$resourceGroup = getResourceGroupName
$purviewName = getPurviewAccountName
"Deploying Purview Account ${purviewName} in Resource Group ${resourceGroup}"
deployPurviewAccount $resourceGroup $location $purviewName
```

`getLocation`, `getResourceGroupName`, `getPurviewAccountName` are basic input functions where I am just asking for names. eg, `centralindia` for location, etc.

The deployement is successful and now I want to add a new collection to my purview account for which I am using the script:

```
<#-CREATES A SERVICE PRINCIPAL-#>
function createSP([string]$subscriptionId, [string]$resourceGroup, [string]$spName) {
$scope = "/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroup}"
$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "${spName}" -Role "Owner" -Scope $scope
return $sp
}
<#-Generates an Access Token#->
function genAccessTok([string]$tenantId, [string]$clientid, [string]$UnsecureSecret) {
$purres = "https://purview.azure.net"
$reqUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/token"
$postmanBody = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${UnsecureSecret}&resource=${purres}"
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $reqUrl -Body $postmanBody -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
$tmpAcsToken = $token.access_token
return "Bearer " + ($tmpAcsToken).ToString()
}

function createSubCollection([string]$accessToken, [string]$endpoint, [string]$collectionName, [string]$parentCollectionName) {
$reqPath = "${endpoint}/account/collections/${purviewName}?api-version=2019-11-01-preview"
$postBody = @{
    "name" = $purviewName
    "parentCollection"= @{
        "type" = "CollectionReference"
        "referenceName" = $parentCollectionName
    }
    "friendlyName" = $collectionName
}
$parameter = @{
    ContentType = "application/json"
    Headers = @{"Authorization"=$accessToken}
    Body = {$postBody | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10}
    Method = "PUT"
    URI = $reqPath
}

Invoke-RestMethod @parameter <#--- Throws error here ---#>
}

$tenantId = (Get-AzContext).Tenant.Id
$subscriptionId = (Get-AzContext).Subscription.Id
$resourceGroup = getResourceGroupName
$purviewName = getPurviewAccountName

$endpoint = "https://${purviewName}.purview.azure.com"
$spName = getServicePrincipleName

$collectionName = getColName
$parentCollectionName = getParentCol
$sp = createSP $subscriptionid $resourceGroup $spName
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($sp.Secret)
$UnsecureSecret = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
$clientid = $sp.ApplicationId

$accessToken = genAccessTok $tenantId $clientid $UnsecureSecret


"Adding Collection to the purview account"

createSubCollection $accessToken $atlas_endpoint $collectionName $parentCollectionName
```

Now to add the collection to my purview account I need to give my service principal created in the  above script "Data Source Admin" role in Purview account. How can I do that through my Powershell script? If I run the above script without giving the role, it throws the following error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> As of now, you can add only adding permission to root collection admin is available. You can use Azure CLI (az purview account add-root-collection-admin) and PowerShell (Add-AzPurviewAccountRootCollectionAdmin)

Once you have access to the purview account, you can add the permission like (Collection admin, Data source admins, Data Curators, Data readers) as per your requirement from Azure Purview Studio.

**Note:** The PowerShell/cli commands for adding permission like (Collection admin, Data source admins, Data Curators, Data readers) are **coming soon**.

For more details, refer to [Access control in Azure Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/catalog-permissions) and You may checkout my previous answer "[azure purview access permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/623846/azure-purview-access-permission.html)" which addressing how to grant access to the Azure Purview account.

Answer (score -1):

Since the last answer is 1,65 year old...

Are there any updates on the possibility to add permissions via Powershell or Cli?

Would be very helpful!

Comment: This could be asked in the comments section, not in answer section.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34234705)